# How to use Input mask jQuery plugin in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, input, mask

I want to implement input mask in my angular 7 project. I need to know the steps to be followed.

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) plugin.

I following the following steps.
Step 1: **npm install inputmask --save** 
Step 2: Imported in my app rounting as **import Inputmask from "inputmask";** 

And in declaration **declarations: [Inputmask ]**

Step 3: In my component.html
`<input data-inputmask="'mask': '[9-]AAA-999'" im-insert="true">`

I am getting following issues:

**Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'Inputmask' imported by the module 'AppRoutingModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.**

How can fix it? Or can i get example code or link.

Comment: You werent supposed to add in AppModule instead of AppRoutingModule ?

Comment: The `import Inputmask from "inputmask"` is only used to import an ES module, not an Angular module. The imported ES module cannot be declared as a angular component/directive. Importing the ES module gives you access to the Inputmask for use in your typescript code, but it doesn't connect it to the angular template.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found out how to fix it.

1. **Install Jquery and inputMask**

   `npm install jquery --save
    npm install inputmask --save`
2. **Add jquery and mask js to angular-cli.json**

   `scripts: [
           "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
           "../node_modules/inputmask/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js" ]`
3. **Import in your component**

   `import * as Inputmask from "inputmask"`
4. **Call it in NgOnInit**

   `ngOnInit() {
       Inputmask().mask(document.querySelectorAll("input"));
     }`
5. **Add mask into input tag**

   `<input data-inputmask="'mask': '99-9999999'" />`